# $F^n$ is a special case of the vector space $F^S$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

in the book Linear Algebra Done Right, $F^S$ is defined as follows:

If $S$ is a set, then $F^S$ denotes the set of functions from $S$ to $F$

where $F$ is a field.

It then writes that $F^n$ is a special case of the vector space $F^S$ because a list of length $n$ of numbers in $F$ can be thought of as a function from $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$ to $F$.

I'm confused on what this means. Consider $n = 2$ and $F = \mathbb{R}$, so the space $\mathbb{R}^2$, This is the familiar Cartesian plane. Based on the book, our set is $S = \{1, 2\}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ is the set of functions from $\{1, 2\}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

I am struggling to reconcile the "set of functions" definition with the traditional notion of $\mathbb{R}^2$ - could someone explain this point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We classically think of $\mathbb R^2$ as the set of ordered pairs $(x,y)$ with $x,y\in\mathbb R$. To view a pair $(x,y)$ as a function $\{1,2\}\to\mathbb R$, we simply map $1\mapsto x$ and $2\mapsto y$. So the elements in the domain of the function represent the place in the ordered pair, and the values of the function represent the numbers in the ordered pair.

More generally, $\mathbb R^n$ is the set of ordered $n$-tuples $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ with $x_1,\ldots,x_n\in\mathbb R$. This can be thought of as a function $\{1,\ldots,n\}\to\mathbb R$ by sending $i\mapsto x_i$ for each $i=1,\ldots,n$.

Comment: A function $f$ from a set ${1,2}$ to the set of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ gives you a set of ordererd pairs $(1, x)$ or $(2, y)$ where $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$. It doesn't give you a set of ordered pairs $(x, y), x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ as does $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. How do you explain that ?

Comment: @David the function I am talking about in my answer sends $i\mapsto x_i$. Varying these functions amounts to varying the real numbers $x_i$. So the set of all such functions gives you the set of all tuples of real numbers.