# Can any one explain this definition in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

I was reading Linear algebra done right and found this statement [image]

but couldnt grasp why F^{1,2,3,..,n} is F^n.
I also found that [$F^n$ is a special case of the vector space $F^S$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4354660/fn-is-a-special-case-of-the-vector-space-fs) which had the same issue, but I dont understand answer.
Shouldn't a function on set S {1, 2} be on its elements 1 and 2 not the whole set at once according to this defintion. [image]

To add more shouldnt I be able to replace these nembers {1,2} by any two numbers even the same numbers.

Comment: It's helpful to think of what you usually think of for vector spaces and then reconcile it with this definition. Let $x\in \mathbb R^2, x = (x_1,x_2) = 3,8$. Now think of $\mathbb R^{\{1,2\}}$ is the set of functions $f: \{1,2\} \to \mathbb R$. If we have $f(1) = 3, f(2) = 8$, then $f\leftrightarrow x$

Comment: that means I can choose f to be on any set of numbers of length 2 like {3, 0.6} given they are not equal. But how can you make sure of the correct ordering. In above example you provided, the resulting vector can be 3,8 or 8,3 so how do you know the correct ordering

Comment: No, the ordering must be 3,8 because $f$ maps 1 to 3 and 2 to 8.

Comment: If you are confused by this point, I would just ignore it. It is not necessary to understand this representation of vectors to follow along with the book.

Comment: yes but how is ordering implied. if f(1) -> 3 and f(2)->8 what says I will read them in this order to get vector (3,8) i can as easily read them in opposite direction and get vector(8,3) as sets has no order

Comment: Nobody writes $x\in \mathbb R^2$ as $x = (x_2,x_1)$

Comment: what do you mean, I am saying that any function f that take set of length n will represent n! vectors as You cant associate which result is first element, is f(1) first element or second.

Comment: Yes, $f(i)$ is the $i$th element.

Comment: so we define vector (x1, x2) as  a specific function f on f(1) and f(2) where f(1) represents first element and f(2) represents second element. if so this means I can also define vector space of R^2 to be R^{2,6} and associate f(2) with first element and f(6) with second element, furthermore I can reverse association meaning f(2) is first element while f(1) is second element, it depends on how we interpret each function on its input, right?